# Prevent ToolStripDropDownButton from being closed as long as no item is clicked

Tags: c#, .net

How can I prevent a ToolStripDropDownButton from being closed until a item or the arrow that opens the menu is clicked?

A standart .net Winforms ToolStripDropDownButton holds its menu just as long open as you hover the menu with the mouse...

I thought of catching it in the closing event and then say e.Cancel = false but unfortunately it seems like ToolStripDropDownButton has no closing event just the ToolStripDropDown

Comment: I made a quick new project in VS2008 and tested this with three items under the DropDownButton -- the menu stays open even if I move the mouse away. Maybe add some more detail (what version of .NET, VS, etc.) to help reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 6):

`ToolStripDropDownButton` is just a wrapper for `ToolStripDropDown`. You can just use its DropDown property to access ToolStripDropDown like this:

```
ToolStripDropDownButton buttonStates = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
buttonStates.DropDown.Closing += new ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler(buttonStatesDropDown_Closing);

private void buttonStatesDropDown_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```